# How to store multiple datas in an Array in swift 4?

Tags: arrays, swift

I am getting a JSON from an API. So, I want to store a particular value with key `SKU`. So, what I did was:

```
    var skuArr = [""]
{ (response, error) in

            if (error != nil)
            {
                print("Error \(error.debugDescription)")
            }

            else
            {
                self.coinsArr = response.arrayObject as? Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>

                for i in 0 ..<  (self.coinsArr?.count)!
                {
                    self.skuArr = [response[i]["sku"].rawValue as! String]
                }
}
```

So, with this I am getting the array in skuArr, but when i is 0 I am getting ["a"], and when i is 1 I want it to be ["a","b"], but it gives ["b"] only and when the loop ends with only the last value and not with ["a","b","c","d"] which I want as the final result. How can I insert each of them in the Array?

Comment: Would you like to post exact response coming from service? By which We can share you the exact parsing logic.

Comment: self.skuArr.append([response[i]["sku"].rawValue as! String])

Comment: probably you should work with [Codable](https://hackernoon.com/everything-about-codable-in-swift-4-97d0e18a2999) here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all declare `skuArr` as **empty** string array.

```
var skuArr = [String]()
```

And this is Swift. There are better ways than ugly index based loops to extract data for example with `map` or `compactMap`

```
if let result = response.arrayObject as? Array<Dictionary<String, Any>> {
    self.coinsArr = result
    self.skuArr = result.compactMap{ $0["sku"] as? String }
}
```

And why is `coinsArr` declared as optional as you are going to force unwrap it anyway? It's highly recommended to use non-optional types as much as possible. **Non-optionals can never cause a well-liked *unexpected found `nil`* crash**

Comment: I have written `var skuArr: [String] = []` like this. Is it okay or should I write like yours?

Comment: Practically it's the same. Personally I prefer the initializer `()` syntax according to `UIImage()`

Comment: Okay. Can I do the same with Set? As I tried and it is not working.

Comment: Try it out. If the compiler doesn't complain you can

Comment: Now, I am defining like this `var skuArr: Set = Set<String>()`. And, using let  `multiple = result.compactMap{ $0["sku"]  as? String }`
`self.skuArr.insert(multiple)`. But throws an error `Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument`

Comment: In case of a `Set` you have to write `self.skuArr.union(multiple)`. And please rename the variable to `skuSet` or something similar.

Comment: It gives error `Result of call to 'union' is unused`

Comment: Please ask a new question and provide more contextual information.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use this:

```
self.skuArr = [response[i]["sku"].rawValue as! String]
```

As this will replace the previous value with new one.

Use `.append` to insert into array.

```
self.skuArr.append([response[i]["sku"].rawValue as! String])
```

**EDIT**

change your initialisation as below:

```
skuArr: [String] = []
```

Comment: Yup got it, just after posting the question, but I am getting it like this ["","a","b"], why I am getting the first empty string?

Comment: becuase you   var skuArr = [""]  here by default at zero index.

Comment: Yeah, got that as well. Thanks for helping.

Comment: change the initialisation. You're adding an empty string at the beginning